# How to do sum of col results from a SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and it results like this:

```
Governors   AUTO    07313570121     1   3.69    2.01    2.01    1.68    83.58%
Governors   AUTO    07319354850     1   2.79    1.8     1.80    0.99    55.00%
Governors   AUTO    07480400400     1   17.69   9.71    9.7117  7.9783  82.15%
Governors   AUTO    07723100038     1   2.89    1.55    1.55    1.34    86.45%
Governors   BEER    01820000031     6   4.69    23.34   3.888   0.8     20.57%
Governors   BEER    01820000051     6   4.69    23.34   3.888   0.802   20.63%
Governors   BEER    01820000106     1   6.39    4.93    4.93    1.46    29.61%
```

i want to sum  like as fallows:

```
 Governors   AUTO  4  27.06  15.07  
 Governors   AUTO  13 13.07  51.61
```

Comment: post your store procedure so we can properly add some fixes.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 6):

without your column names it's a little bit tricky, but it would be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
  col1 varchar(50),
  col2 varchar(4),
  col3 varchar(11),
  col4 int,
  col5 decimal(18,2),
  col6 decimal(18,2),
  col7 decimal(18,2),
  col8 decimal(18,2),
  col9 decimal(18,2) --might need to be varchar if the % sign comes back
)

insert into #MyTable
Exec storedProc

select col1, col2, sum(col4), sum(col5), sum(col7)
FROM #MyTable
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. The data comes from a stored procedure

Comment: @JamesMohler - I missed that it was a stored proc. See updated answer